# Creating dataset of 4 variables in

Tags: r

I am trying to format flux data, but need to create a dataset with days of the year, year and hour in the format:

```
DoY   Year   Hour  Plot
1     2018   0.5   A11
1     2018   1.0   A11
1     2018   1.5   A11
```

but for **hours** `(seq(0.5,24,0.5))`, **DoY** `(seq(1,365,1))` and **plots** `(c("A11", "A12", "A13",  "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17","A18",  "A21",  "A22", "A23", "A24","A25", "A26",  "A27", "A28", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38",  "A41","A42", "A43",  "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", "E11", "E12",  "E13","E14", "E15", "E16", "E17", "E18",  "E21", "E22", "E23", "E24", "E25", "E26",  "E27", "E28", "E31", "E32", "E33", "E34", "E35", "E36", "E37", "E38", "E41", "E42","E43", "E44", "E45", "E46", "E47",  "E48", "E51", "E52", "E53", "E54", "E55", "E56", "E57", "E58"))` across the three **years** 2018-2021

By my reckoning, it should create a dataset around 34736 rows long, but I do not know how to create a dataset with just these values in (I need to to further merge three other datasets).

Any help or advice would be gratefully recieved!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `expand.grid` to get all combinations of `Hour`, `DOY`, `plots` and `years` in a dataframe but this does not give data which is 34736 rows long.

```
Hour <- seq(0.5,24,0.5)
DOY <- seq(1,365,1)
plots <- c("A11", "A12", "A13",  "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17","A18",  "A21",  "A22", "A23", "A24","A25", "A26",  "A27", "A28", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38",  "A41","A42", "A43",  "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", "E11", "E12",  "E13","E14", "E15", "E16", "E17", "E18",  "E21", "E22", "E23", "E24", "E25", "E26",  "E27", "E28", "E31", "E32", "E33", "E34", "E35", "E36", "E37", "E38", "E41", "E42","E43", "E44", "E45", "E46", "E47",  "E48", "E51", "E52", "E53", "E54", "E55", "E56", "E57", "E58")
years <- 2018:2021
data <- expand.grid(Hour = Hour, DOY = DOY, plots = plots, years = years)
```